Xero API with webhooks - tenantId in payload not matching
Been working with the xero API using a custom connection to the xero demo account, all good so far in postman and my .net app, can create invoices, contacts etc.
Next step is setting up webhook listener. I've set it up on my dev env, all good with postman, signatures match etc. Awesome.
Except when I initiate an intent to receive, I get 401 unauthorised errors, and therefore my code returns 401 to the web.
My tenantId for the demo account starts with 9748f2b3-. This matches what I expect when I call https://api.xero.com/connections.
The webhook fails, and viewing history, again shows the correct tenantId of 9748f2b3-...., however the debug logs shows the payload sent contains json payload with a tenantId of 38356695-..... so obviously when I try hit the resourceUrl I get an authorised error, nor can connect using postman. I'd expect the json payload to have a tenantid of 9748f2b3-.
After several hours of trying things like deleting the custom connection, reconnecting, rewriting code I've admitted defeat. I've no doubt missed something obvious, any pointers?
Edit - Just for a test, I set my webhook listener to return a 200 code even if it fails, so intent to receive is now setup. I then went to the demo account and amended an invoice, checked the json payload in debug and it shows the correct tenantId of 9748f2b3-. So it works, but what the heck is going on with the intent to receive?! Why wouldnt it use the same tenantId?

I think more specific information is needed to debug this and so could you raise a case with Xero support here and provide the client id for your app
